# BackTick in JavaScript Throws 500 On Some Environments (Angularjs page)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, iis

Have a really odd issue.  Have an old AngularJs page where some JavaScript will work on all of my development servers, but not in Production.  I use the same browser so I know that isn't the issue.

For example:

Works everywhere EXCEPT Production:

`` var drug = $(`#Grid tr:contains('${drugs[i].barcode}')`); ``

Works everywhere INCLUDING Production:

`var drug = $("#Grid tr:contains('" + drugs[i].barcode + "')");`

And...

Works everywhere EXCEPT Production:

```
$.post("/Page/Refresh", { id }, function () {
      self.fetch(id);
});
```

Works everywhere INCLUDING Production:

```
$http.post("/Page/Refresh", { id }).success(function () {
     self.fetch(id);
});
```

All of this code is in an Angularjs module so I think that has something to do with it.  What I don't understand is why it works on ALL environments except Production.  Obviously something is different, but I haven't been able to figure out what exactly it is.  It's not fun to find these errors only when I roll to Production - so I am hoping I can figure out what setting is different.

Comment: If I use developer tools I will see a 500 Internal Error

Comment: Another note - this is an ASP.NET MVC Web Site

Comment: Could you please post the details error message about the 500 error?